# Using react-md, what is the best way to check for mobile, tablet or desktop client?

Tags: react-md

Is there a general way of determining whether a device is mobile/tablet or desktop?

I.e. something like the following:

```
<SomeComponent defaultVisible={props.isMobile ? true : false} />
```

I see there is a 'class function' - `getCurrentMedia()` - https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/navigation-drawers?tab=1#drawertypes

But I don't know how to use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation:

A `class function` is a function defined as a static reference on a class. In my case I'm using the `NavigationDrawer` component, which is a component defined as a JavaScript class - so a class function `getCurrentMedia` is accessed like the following:

```
NavigationDrawer.getCurrentMedia()
```